# Why calling a function would increase the page reclaims?

Tags: c

Consider the code below:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  free(NULL);
  return (0);
}
```

When I run it with the command `/usr/bin/time -l ./a.out` to get number of page reclaims, I get these statistics:

```bash
        0.00 real         0.00 user         0.00 sys
    729088  maximum resident set size
         0  average shared memory size
         0  average unshared data size
         0  average unshared stack size
 ----> 199  page reclaims
         0  page faults
         0  swaps
         0  block input operations
         0  block output operations
         0  messages sent
         0  messages received
         0  signals received
         0  voluntary context switches
         1  involuntary context switches
```

But when I test it without calling `free(NULL)` I get lower number of page reclaims, which doesn't make sense.

```bash
        0.00 real         0.00 user         0.00 sys
    716800  maximum resident set size
         0  average shared memory size
         0  average unshared data size
         0  average unshared stack size
 ----> 195  page reclaims
         0  page faults
         ...
```

Can someone please give me a clear explination why this behaviour occurres?

Comment: `ls -l ./a.out` doesn't run `a.out`.

Comment: sorry, I meant using `/usr/bin/time -l ./a.out`. I've edited the question.

Comment: Increase the number of pages of memory needed to store your program, and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: A simple call to `free(NULL)` that litterally doesn't do anything in the memory (or so I think, correct me if I'm wrong) would not cause the pages  to the get higher, no?

Comment: How consistent is this? I'd expect page reclamations to be very sensitive to other things running on the system.

Comment: I consistent on every run

Comment: The difference in memory use is 12,288 bytes. Divide by 4096, round up, and you have your difference of four pages.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Shouldn't `free()` be in a shared library that's almost always loaded  into memory?

Comment: @Barmar, agreed that it'll already be in physical memory.

Comment: @Glitch, ...so, here's a test if you want to put my theory to it: Increase the RSS size in a way that _doesn't_ involve calling any functions, and see if that changes the page fault count. I'm betting that it will.

Comment: Is this a debug version?

Comment: @Weather Vane It's just a simple test to understand page reclaims

Comment: @CharlesDuffy It is true that the page faults changes, it actually increased by 1 and decreased page reclaims by same amount. But still, it doesn't make sense to increase page reclaimes by 4 pages just by calling a function.

Comment: @Glitch, how doesn't it make sense? You're changing the size of your code when you make it link in more dependencies at runtime and then add the additional code to invoke those dependencies. That means that the number of pages that get deallocated during shutdown changes by at least that change in size.